# Ruby on Rails - CanCan Gem with Many to Many Through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

On Rails 4. I'm having trouble understanding how to authorize users to be able to edit their organization's information through CanCan.

Use Case 1: Users have many organizations; organizations have many users. This relationship information is stored in the third model, UserOrganization (with `:user_id` and `:organization_id` attributes). So basically, users are able to edit org info as long as they are linked through that third model. I learned about this piece of code but it does not work (in ability.rb):

```
def initialize(user)
  can [:show, :edit, :update], Organization, user_organizations: { user_id: user.id }
end
```

(says undefined method user_id)

Use Case 2: There is a fourth model, OrganizationDetails. One organization can have many organization_details. I would also like the user to be able to edit his/her organization's details.

In other words, Users -> has many -> UserOrganizations -> belongs to -> Organizations -> has many -> OrganizationDetails.

How do I format this in CanCan so a user can create/edit those org details he/she is linked to through the UserOrganization model. Thanks. All controllers have `load_and_authorize_resource` and the appropriate `has_many` and `belongs_to` code in the models.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to do this.

To restrict by Organization:

```
can [:show, :edit, :update], Organization do |organization|
  UserOrganization.where(user_id: user.id, organization_id: organization.id).any?
end
```

To restrict by OrganizationDetail

```
can [:show, :edit, :update], OrganizationDetail do |organization_detail|
  UserOrganization.where(user_id: user.id, organization_id: organization_detail.organization.id).any?
end
```